# Open App Permissions on Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to show all apps and permissions via list from the system to the user. I know that this setting available for API >= 23 in different locations.

For API >= 26 it is on:

> Settings / Apps & Notifications / Advanced / App permissions

For API >= 23 it is on:

> Settings / Apps / Configure Apps (Setting menu item) / App permissions

Is there any way to open ***App permissions*** screen using intent?

[image: Android App permissions settings]

Comment: @NileshRathod not related to that one, check the screenshot that I attached to the question, please. I do not want to open my apps settings, I want to open the "App permissions" screen to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you will be lucky and someone can prove me wrong, but it seems on recent version of Android you are limited to App Settings only - no direct access to App Permissions via Intent.

I believe this is related to Security and Automation which would also align with Googles decision to show an 'overlay detected' warning when trying to request permissions [as outlined on this non-Google article](https://www.howtogeek.com/271519/how-to-fix-the-screen-overlay-detected-error-on-android/)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("App permissions");
    adb.setMessage("Click on ok then app will redirect to app settings then please click on Other Permissions and Please Allow All");
    adb.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    adb.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finishAffinity();
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    adb.show();
}
```