# Is it possible to open Location permission screen programatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

After a user clicks a button, I need to open the settings on the screen with a list of apps that have access to the location.

[image: location permission screen]

I didn't find it in the list of constants for intent: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings nor in Settings in provider.

Does it mean that it is not possible by the Intent? If so, is there some other way?

**Similar questions**

Please note that [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android) question is asking for permission for an app, while I am asking for the list of apps with location permission.

[Open App Permissions on Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758533/open-app-permissions-on-android-programmatically/52759143#52759143) is asking for the screen with a list of the permissions, which is closer to what I need, but still not the same. Also, there is no direct answer.

---

To address the first answer and all possible next answers: I am importing correctly android.provider.Settings.
ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS is Location settings, but I need Location permission settings.