# Open permissions manager settings page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I try to open the permission manager screen from the settings but I don't found the good Intent.

I try :

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_PRIVACY_SETTINGS))
```

But it open the Privacy page of the settings and if I want to show the permission manager screen, I have to click on the sub-element "Permission manager" :
[image]

I want to open this page :
[image]

How can I do ?

Comment: I believe it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52758533/12478830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to directly access `privacy -> permission manager`. Here are all actions that you can access. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings

Answer (score 1):

You can't open permissions page directly. However, you can use Intents to open the app's settings screen, from which, you can open the permission settings with one click:

Kotlin:

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).apply {
    data = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
})
```

Java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

cr: [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to open settings for permissions, reason is defined in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759143/5890471

However you can take permissions from the user in a traditional way by:

```kotlin
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
```

and define your required permissions in manifest!